# Why doesn't converting an object in javascript to and from JSON return the object?

Tags: javascript, json

I'm having an issue comparing objects encoded and decoded to and from JSON

```
//Test data
var test_obj = {
    test:'value',
    t:3,
    x:[0,5,3]
};
var t = JSON.stringify(test_obj);
var t_prime = JSON.parse(t);
```

You'd think that `test_obj === t_prime` would return true,
or perhaps `test_obj == t_prime` would return true, but this is not the case.

Why is this, and how can I verify that I get the same object to and from a javascript object to JSON?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you determine equality for two JavaScript objects?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/201183/how-do-you-determine-equality-for-two-javascript-objects)

Comment: Can you compare your objects in json format? JSON.stringify(test_obj) === JSON.stringify(t_prime)

Comment: @Vertigo I suppose I could, that's probably most reliable i this case.

Comment: Comparing the JSON strings *might* work, but there's nothing that guarantees the properties of the two objects will be serialized in the same order.  (Object properties have no real "order" imposed on them by the JS specs, last i checked.)  Translation: two objects with the same properties might not end up with the exact same JSON serialization.  In fact, AFAIK, JS doesn't even guarantee that *the same object serialized twice* will give you two identical strings.  Just so happens that most implementations are deterministic enough that people don't think about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you compare objects in JS, you are checking to see if they are *the same object* and not *identical objects*.

Converting to JSON turns an object into a string. Converting from JSON creates a *new* object based on the JSON data.

If you want to check if two objects are identical, then see [How do you determine equality for two JavaScript objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201183/how-do-you-determine-equality-for-two-javascript-objects).